# Conversion from VGG19 to ResNet in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, resnet, vgg-net

I have the following code which works on pre-trained VGG model but fails on ResNet and Inception model.

```
vgg_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet')
type(vgg_model)
vgg_model.summary()
model = Sequential()
for layer in vgg_model.layers:
    model.add(layer)
```

Now, changing the model to ResNet as follows:

```
resnet_model=keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
type(resnet_model)
resnet_model.summary()
model = Sequential()
for layer in resnet_model.layers:
    model.add(layer)
```

gives the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer res2a_branch1: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 64 but got shape (None, 56, 56, 256)
```

Comment: Why do you want to transform a pretrained model into a Sequential?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to the fact that unlike VGG, Resnet does not have a sequential architecture (e.g. some layers are connected to more than one layers, there are skip connections, etc.). Therefore you cannot iterate over the layers in the model one after another and connect each layer to the previous one (i.e. sequentially). You can plot the architecture of the model using [`plot_model()`](https://keras.io/visualization/) to have a better understanding of this point.

Comment: @KaranArya As I mentioned, there is no way to convert a non-sequential model to a sequential model. And I am not sure why you are interested to do that. But, if you explain what your final aim is maybe we can help you better.

Comment: My final aim is to run a multi class classification using ResNet.

Comment: @KaranArya So you don't need to convert ResNet to sequential model for doing that. Just use it as it is (probably you also need to add custom layers on top). See [this tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) (specifically its last section: "Fine-tuning the top layers of a a pre-trained network").